# Grub2 with BURG: duplicate Windows entries, how do I remove one?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, dual-boot

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, using GRUB2 (with Burg) as boot loader.

For some reason, the Windows installation shows up twice in the boot menu:

```
Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic
Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (recovery mode)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
```

If I look in my partition table, `/dev/sda2` is C:\ of the Windows installation, and `/dev/sda1` is the "System Reserved" partition (which, IIRC, is Windows' own bootloader). Furthermore, gparted shows `/dev/sda2` - but no other partitions - with a `boot` flag:

[image]

What is going on here? I'd like to have only the entries for Ubuntu and *one* entry for Windows in my boot menu - how do I remove one of them?

Comment: @EliahKagan: **no!** the first one contains the rescue image AND the bootloader by default -- the root partition is NOT set bootable or contain a bootloader.

Comment: @izx Can you explain in more detail? By default, *some* boot loader has to be installed to the MBR, and when Windows is the only OS, that's the Windows boot loader. Do you mean some part of the boot loader bootstraps into some other part, located in the first partition? (As you can see I'm not deeply knowledgeable about the architecture of the Windows boot loader, in recent Windows OSes.) Furthermore, unless I'm recalling incorrectly, I've always been able to boot Windows 7 systems like this by selecting the second option in GRUB2.

Comment: @EliahKagan The "reserved" partition contains `bootmgr` and the BCD store (call it bootmgr.cfg); bootmgr presents the selection menu, etc. but if you select Windows, it will chainload it from the root partition. The MBR code per se just loads `bootmgr` into memory. [See this bcdedit pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1020800/). I temporarily assigned `Q:` to the reserved partition; the "Windows Boot Loader" section contains the parameters telling `bootmgr` how to chainload. If you assign a drive letter, you'll see that `dir /ah Q:` contains `bootmgr` and the `Boot` dir, but `dir /ah C:` doesnt.

Comment: @EliahKagan Compare the first entry in the above pastebin to [this one](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1020802/) from my laptop, which (deliberately) doesn't have the reserved partition but puts everything on `C:`.  BTW, when the drive assignment `Q:` is removed, it reverts to `partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that Windows 7 puts it's "boot" partition on `/dev/sda1` by default, but it is possible to get Win 7 to put the everything on its "root" partition too -- e.g. by installing to a pre-formatted NTFS partition.

Perhaps you have tweaked Windows in the past such that the bootloader/bootable flag went on `/dev/sda2`? Can you successfully boot from **both** Windows entries? If so, it's safe to delete one of them.

#### How to remove the entries

> ## Danger!
>
> This may make your Windows unbootable; to follow the steps below you'll have to insert `sudo` where appropriate and make sure the NTFS partition is mounted read-write beforehand.

```
cd /mnt/where-o-where-my-ntfs-be
rm -rf bootmgr Boot BOOTSECT.BAK Recovery
cd && umount /mnt/ntfs1
update-grub
```

That *should* do it - obviously I haven't tried on my dual-boot system(s). Please let me know if it doesn't work and I'll either give you more dangerous methods or maybe look in the `grub` source to see how it detects Windows partitions for a definitive answer.

Comment: I've now confirmed that I can safely boot into both Windows entries. It is absolutely possible that I installed Windows into a partition that was already formatted as NTFS, but I do not remember selecting any options about not using the standard setup - would the installer automatically have put the bootloader on the C:\ partition anyway, since it was all NTFS already?

Comment: Anyway, removing one of the entries from the boot menu is enough for me - I don't really care whether the two partitions are still bootable or not, as long as only one shows up in the menu :P

Comment: @TomasLycken: See edited answer

Comment: I took the "safe road" and moved all those files and folders to a subfolder "backup" instead. After `update-grub` and `update-burg` my Windows installation only shows up once, and boots fine! However, I now have greater problems - Ubuntu won't boot at all...! `update-burg` gave a message to the effect that "the input file `grub.cfg.new` was the same as the output file", but didn't say that it was a problem. Apparently, it was anyway? How do I fix my Ubuntu installation now?

Comment: @TomasLycken: I'd recommend starting a new question. I haven't played with `burg` in a while but will try to look into it in the morning (tag me with an @ in a comment so I know). In the meanwhile, if you decide to take the new question route and feel this answer helped you out, please accept it.

Comment: I took the "easy" way out, and just reinstalled grub from a Live USB instead. This way I can get it all right from the beginning instead of trying to fix my mistakes :P Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to know...you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I've it already solved persistently enough for my needs. I've changed /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober script a little:

start at line 150 (just add variable and condition to check if windows 7 has already been found):

```
wubi=

for OS in ${OSPROBED} ; do
  DEVICE="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 1`"
  LONGNAME="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr '^' ' '`"
  LABEL="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 3 | tr '^' ' '`"
  BOOT="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 4`"

  if [ -z "${LONGNAME}" ] ; then
    LONGNAME="${LABEL}"
  fi

  echo "Found ${LONGNAME} on ${DEVICE}" >&2
```

change to:

```
wubi=
windows7_found=

for OS in ${OSPROBED} ; do
  DEVICE="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 1`"
  LONGNAME="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr '^' ' '`"
  LABEL="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 3 | tr '^' ' '`"
  BOOT="`echo ${OS} | cut -d ':' -f 4`"

  if [ -z "${LONGNAME}" ] ; then
    LONGNAME="${LABEL}"
  fi

  # Mi-La patch to add Windows 7 only once
  if [ "${LONGNAME}" = "Windows 7 (loader)" ]; then
    if [ "${windows7_found}" = yes ]; then
      echo "Skipping duplicated entry for ${LONGNAME} on ${DEVICE}." >&2
      continue
    else
      windows7_found=yes
    fi
  fi

  echo "Found ${LONGNAME} on ${DEVICE}" >&2
```

Should be working at least till grub won't be updated.
Enjoy.

**EDIT: Ubuntu 12.10**

30_os-prober changed a little, but using the same if after the following lines:

```
  if [ -z "${LONGNAME}" ] ; then
    LONGNAME="${LABEL}"
  fi
```

works well.

Comment: Currently the easiest way is to use GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST.
See the following [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453038/update-grub-ignoring-some-options-in-etc-default-grub#answer-514205)

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the Burg configuration file via Terminal:
1.) Open Terminal
2.) Type

```
Sudo gedit /boot/burg/burg.cfg
```

3.) Find the menuentry "Windows..." and just after --class os add:

```
--group group_secondary
```

Where "group_secondary" is a unique name to group a group of operating systems together. If you look at the file, you'll see that the Linux kernels have:

```
--group group_main
```

Now you should have Windows and Windows Recovery look like:

```
menuentry "Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sdc1)" --class windows --class os --group group_secondary {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd2,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set b896bf7f96bf3d26
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sdc2) (recovery mode)" --class windows --class os --group group_secondary {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd2,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c46cc0a06cc08f1c
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

4.) The MOST IMPORTANT PART!!! Save!!! Now you can either REBOOT or Start :

```
sudo burg-emu
```

5.) On the selection screen press "F" to collapse the folders.

***SIDE NOTE: When collapsed, Burg will use the FIRST menuentry in the file as the default in collapsed mode.

Answer (score -2):

sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Then comment the second Windows entry (sda2), i.e., put a '#' from where the entry begins. It will remove the entry without affecting your files.
Same goes for burg as well.
Just replace grub with burg in the command.

Comment: That doesn't work for Grub2 because `grub.cfg` is updated on every `update-grub` run, which is upon every kernel upgrade at least.

Comment: So will you be updating your kernel everyday?? :P
It worls and barely takes a minute. What is the problem??

Comment: @AkshitBaunthiyal: It's a very temporary solution - having to do this after every kernel upgrade (or even every change to my boot menu) would be seriously annoying, even if it's not that often.